# Stringbuilder and DataAdapter.Update duplicating lines

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

I have a DataTable similar to

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5  Date

 21   22   23   24   25   7/25/2014 12:00:00 AM
 31   32   33   34   35   7/25/2014 12:00:00 AM
 11   12   13   14   15   7/25/2014 12:00:00 AM
```

and I loop through it as

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Col1\tCol2\tCol3\tCol4\tCol5\tDate\n");
foreach(DataRow row in partTable.Select()) {
    output.AppendLine(String.Join("\t", row.ItemArray.ToArray()));
}
```

and do some formatting using `StringBuilder.Replace` on output.  I print the result to a `MessageBox` and it duplicates my rows.  The first time I call this it prints 2 copies, the next it prints 3, etc.  ([After one call.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAw0k.jpg)) I have checked repeatedly that the table is correct and doesn't contain duplicates.  Below is the full code for this function.

```
private void printTable() {
        updateDataSet();
        if (partTable.Rows.Count == 0) {
            MessageBox.Show("Table is empty.", "Table");
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder("Col1\tCol2\tCol3\tCol4\tCol5\tDate\n");
        foreach(DataRow row in partTable.Select()) {
            output.AppendLine(String.Join("\t", row.ItemArray.ToArray()));
        }
        // Get rid of time and type
        output.Replace("12:00:00 AM", "");
        output.Replace("W\t", "");
        MessageBox.Show(output.ToString(), "Table");
        output.Clear();
}
```

Solution Implemented: Commenting out updateDataSet() removes the duplication.  I guess I just need to try to read MSDN more carefully...  Replaced `Fill` with `Update`, but it would not remove any rows I deleted.  Used a combination of `Clear` and `Fill` to get an updated table without recreating the connection.

Comment: My guess is your problem is in updateDataSet()

Comment: Tested the code part that build the stringbuilder and nothing strange happens there. So the problem is in the partTable. Print the number of rows present and verify if it is equal to your expected count

Comment: And yes, looking at your picture it seems clear that you add another set of rows to the datatable as @GrantWinney says

Comment: How many times do you run the `output.AppendLine` iteration? is it the number you expect? what is `partTable.Rows.Count` ?

Comment: updateDataSet() calls `DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` for my DataSet.  From MSDN's help on the command, it should only create a new row if it does not already exist (odd that they don't use "distinct" to describe it). Am I wrong in understanding that? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/905keexk(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "Am I wrong in understanding that?" - yes, probably - at least, that behaviour depends a lot on the exact configuration. Frankly, you're better off not relying on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call two times the `DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable)` method you double the records present in your datatable. To avoid this behaviour you need to write (inside the updateDataSet() method)

```
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(.....)
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
da.Fill(dt);

// Just for testing
// Check these results with and without the MissingSchemaAction flag
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows.Count);
da.Fill(dt);
Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows.Count);
```

Of course, the presence of `MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey` results in poorer performances if you don't remove the cause of the second (or third call) to `updateDataSet()` Infact, in this scenario the loading method should check every row present to find duplicates.

Comment: I'm actually using an Oracle database, so it's `OleDbDataAdapter`, and I used `Update` to avoid creating an entirely new connection.  But this is the right track of what fixed the problem and would help anyone else who sees this who misunderstood `Fill` like I did. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please put all your code for analysis.
Also, there is logic/design issue in the code which has been provided. 
PrintTable method is expected to read and print data only. UpdateDataset is breaking intention of code.